# IE is adding unwanted random <span> tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have two text field. In one i am inserting one link. I am copying that link and pasting it the second one. Now when i am opening the source of the 2nd  text field where i pasted it shows an extra  tag is added. This issue is only in IE. I am using IE9.

This is the source code of the first text field where i inserted the link::

```
<p> 
   <a id="hhh" href="http://blr-kprama-lt:8080/_$link-ref:'2975'_" >sffsf </a>
</p>
```

This is the source code of the second field where i pasted the link.

```
<p> 
      <a id="hhh" href="http://blr-kprama-lt:8080/_$link-ref:'2975'_" >
        <span style="color: #0066cc" >sffsf </span></a>
</p>
```

Give me some idea or code snippet.

Comment: Do you use some kind of web editor (CKeditor)? Please make it clear in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by inserting a link in a text field? You cannot do such a thing in HTML.

Comment: I am working in a CMS tool. Where we have a functionality which is "Add link"..if i select some text and then do add link t,that text becomes a link.@ jukka k. korpela

Comment: Yes we are using an web editor, Wysiwyg editor @peter ivan

Comment: What is the source if you paste it back into the first text field?  Please, improve your question. What have you done to resolve the problem? Poor question means poor interest in answering.

Comment: Yes i tried to paste the same in the first text field. And an extra <span> is added here also. @Peter Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `<span>` with that `style` attribute around your `<p>` tag. Since it's not valid to have a `<p>` inside a `<span>`, the browser corrects the error for you.